# The Java Web Translator library

Tags: java

please ,can you help me for using of this library"The Java Web Translator library"
in my applicatin ,or give me an example; how i can use it in my code java?
I have seen the google api translator but i chose JWT because it's
provides automatic language translation to the client's locale.
Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation? It's here : http://sourceforge.net/projects/webtranslator/files/JavaWebTranslator-0.2a/Java%20WebTranslator%200.2a%20%28Alpha%20Release%29/

Download the zip documentation file, unzip it, and open the index.html file. It contains a quick start guide and other useful material.